# Nested maybe and nullable

Tags: purescript, option-type

Having trouble untangling maybe and nullable values in the following:

```
container <-
  unsafePartial
  (fromJust <<< toMaybe
  <$> DOM.querySelector (DOM.QuerySelector "body")
  (DOM.htmlDocumentToParentNode document))
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Could not match type
>
> Maybe
>
> with type
>
> Nullable
>
> while trying to match type Maybe Element
>    with type Nullable t1
>   while checking that expression (querySelector (QuerySelector "body"))
>   (htmlDocumentToParentNode document)
>    has type t0 (Nullable t1)
>   in value declaration main
>
> where t0 is an unknown type
>        t1 is an unknown type

I've tried but I can't find my way through the various types being used here
(code is originally from [here](https://github.com/kRITZCREEK/electron-apps-with-purescript/blob/master/src/Main.purs))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend breaking this up a bit.

Start with

```
do body <- DOM.querySelector (DOM.QuerySelector "body")
             (DOM.htmlDocumentToParentNode document))
   ?whatNext
```

Here, `?whatNext` is a typed hole. The compiler will tell you the inferred type of the hole, which should help you to figure out what to replace it with.

Also note that you can simplify things a little by applying `unsafePartial` to `fromJust` directly, to give a function of type `Maybe a -> a`.

Comment: Yes, eventually I got it to work by applying unsafePartial and fromJust directly to container in the last line. Thanks for informing me of typed holes, looks very useful, although in this case it suggest the usafeCoerce which didn't work.

Comment: Yes, not every suggestion will work. It just means it'll type-check.